# Is it possible to extract only Guided Decision table part from Drools Workbench?

Tags: jboss, drools, workbench, drools-guvnor, kie-workbench

Am using drools workbench 6.4.0 Final.

I need to show only Guided decision tables part in my web application. I have gone through drools documentation and online resources, but i could not find any related resources.

currently i embedded workbench in my application using iframe, but i want to extract only guided decision table part and integrate it in my web application.

Is there any documentation to extract decision table part from work bench ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the embed editor mode. This might be what you are already doing. With the correct parameters it makes it possible to just embed a single editor in an iframe.

If this is not enough, you can take the source code for the Guided Decision Table from [here](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools-wb/tree/master/drools-wb-screens/drools-wb-guided-dtable-editor). The editor is written with GWT and it has quite a lot of dependencies like Errai and Uberfire. Not to mention dependencies on workbench internal services like Data Model Oracle that provides the information about models you are using, the DSL and DRL editors and internal compiler.

So while it is possible to use the codes because they are free and open source. You need to do a lot of work before you get a working editor in your own application. There is no documentation and it is not supported, but extracting the editor is possible.